# Need Help Applying filters, select, 2 option values vs 1, Javascript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add an extra option value "9" to both Afghanistan and Albania.  Example: SO when i apply filter Albania and 1 Pound, I get both both results: $41 and $22.

HTML:

```
<p>Filter: </p>
    <select class="filterby">
        <option value="L"><h5>Afghanistan</h5></option>
        <option value="E"><h5>Albania</h5></option>
    </select>

<p>Location: </p>
    <select class="filterby">
         <option value="1"><h5>1 Pound</h5></option>
         <option value="2"><h5>2 Pound</h5></option>
    </select>

<div id="FilterContainer">
    <div class="E 1">$41</div>
    <div class="E 2">$48</div>

    <div class="L 1">$28</div>
    <div class="L 2">$33</div>

    <div class="9 1">$22</div>
    <div class="9 2">$25</div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function(){
    $('#FilterContainer').hide();

    $("select.filterby").change(function(){
        var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
            return $(e).val();
        }).join(".");
        $("div#FilterContainer").find("div").hide();
    $('#FilterContainer').show(); 
        $("div#FilterContainer").find("div." + filters).show(); 
    });
    }//]]> 

</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/doLy6yp9/16/

Answer (score 0):

i added attribute to the options of first select which we can consider that attribute as the second value you want to add :

```
<p>Filter: </p>
    <select class="filterby" id="allCountries">
        <option value="L" dataSec="8"><h5>Afghanistan</h5></option>
        <option value="E" dataSec="9"><h5>Albania</h5></option>
    </select>

<p>Location: </p>
    <select class="filterby">
         <option value="1"><h5>1 Pound</h5></option>
         <option value="2"><h5>2 Pound</h5></option>
    </select>

<div id="FilterContainer">
    <div class="E 1">$41</div>
    <div class="E 2">$48</div>

    <div class="L 1">$28</div>
    <div class="L 2">$33</div>

    <div class="9 1">$22</div>
    <div class="9 2">$25</div>

</div>
```

and js:

```
$('#FilterContainer').hide();

  $("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
      return $(e).val();
    });
    var secondVal = $("#allCountries option:selected").attr('dataSec');


    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div").hide();
    $('#FilterContainer').show(); 
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div." + filters.join('.')).show(); 
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div." + secondVal + "." + filters[1]).show(); 
  });
```

demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/bwhrj68r/1/

Comment: Thank you very much Ahmed. Works Great..  But now I only want to apply option value 9 to Albania, Not Afghanistan.  for Afghanistan I want to apply a different value say: 8  Is there another method? I will deploy this on larger scale for 220 contries, each country will have a letter and number option value applied to it.

Comment: Sorry @Safian I had not understand well so I edited the answer please check it, I hope that it is what you want .

Comment: Thank you so much Ahmed, you saved me hours of trying to figure this out on my own.  I am not much of a developer instead a systems engineer. I reverse engineer most things but this would have taken me days!!!